# Supporting multiple iOS versions

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ecslidingviewcontroller

I'm using a library called ECSlidingViewController in my app. However this lib has two different versions, one for iOS 7 and one for older versions.

Since the different versions use the same method signatures but are defined in different files, checking the current version using `UIDevice` is not really an option, as that doesn't allow me to import the correct version. From what I understand iOS apps are not compiled per version but rather as a Universal binary.

So how do I solve this? Someone must have had this problem before.

Comment: Rename the class in one version

Comment: and make a bridge class where you migrate the two selectors on the go.

Comment: The two above comments are great. I have another one for you which is what I did. Write your own.

Comment: The problem is that the different versions use widely different implementations. I solved it by duplicating the classes that access ECSlidingViewController, as I only had two classes (About 150 LOC). Not the best solution but it seems to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up duplicating the classes that use `ECSlidingViewController` and calling the correct version of the library.